# Why do they use absolute value symbols for $|z|=r$ considering any number squared is positive?

Tags: notation

Am I right in saying that the absolute value symbols act like a function such that if $x$, for example, is $x<0$ then $x=-x$

In other words $x$ will be positive regardless of what value you give to $x$, right?

In which case, isn't $|z|$ always positive? Considering $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, where $z=a+bi$.

Comment: Actually $|z|$ is always non-negative. It's not clear to me what your objection is.

Comment: $|z|$ is always nonnegative; $|0|=0$.

Comment: I can't tell if this is relevant, but notice that $\sqrt{z^2}$ is not necessarily a real number (e.g. if $z=i$ or any non-real number) and does not equal $|z|$.

Comment: Now, Thomas, the way your question is worded makes me think that you're complaining that the absolute value symbol is somehow redundant, unnecessary or pointless. Am I reading you wrong?

Comment: @Robert Soupe This question is half a rant and half a way of trying to understand why they chose the absolute value symbol. For real numbers they mean one thing, for complex numbers they mean another. I understand that they both find the distance from the origin. But in terms of them being a function it's very easy to get confused. I personally think that they should have used a different symbol for each, perhaps a symbol that looks similar but not identical.

Comment: Unlike 20th century composers, mathematicians have never liked inventing new symbols. If a symbol already exists that means something slightly similar to what they want, they prefer to overload that symbol. And if there's no existing symbol with a similar meaning, then maybe just overload parentheses with yet another meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the absolute value of a number is always non-negative (Zero if the input is zero, positive otherwise).

This is the point of the absolute value function; it is in some sense a measure of the *size* of the number. To be more precise, the absolute value of a number is the distance from the number to the origin.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not sure if $|z|$ can be equal to zero, however if it can all $|z|$ is telling you is that it is not less than zero, right? Since it'll always be nonnegative.

Comment: $|z| = 0$ if and only if $z=0$. Can you clarify a bit on what you are confused about?

Comment: Is this just with complex numbers? I thought that the absolute value symbols are essentially just used to "force" a positive result. Whereas with complex numbers it's seems they're used to represent a function to find the distance from the origin

Comment: Sorry "nonnegative" rather than positive

Comment: What I have written is true for both real and complex numbers. Consider the real number line, then the number $-5$ is of distance $5$ away from $0$ (the origin), hence $|-5| = 5$. For real numbers, however, this turns out to be the same as just "forcing the number to be non-negative."

Comment: Awesome, this is why I love math

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in saying that the absolute value symbols act like a
>   function such that if $x$, for example, is $x<0$ then $x=-x$

Yes, if you would add bars: $\lvert x \rvert = -x$ for $x < 0$.

The definition is
$$
\lvert x \rvert =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccl}
x & \mbox{ for } & x > 0 & \Rightarrow \mbox{positive sign} \\
0 & \mbox{ for } & x = 0 & \Rightarrow \mbox{no sign} \\
-x & \mbox{ for } & x < 0 & \Rightarrow \mbox{positive sign} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Therefore $\lvert x \rvert$ is always positive or zero, thus non-negative.

> In other words $x$ will be positive regardless of what value you give
>   to $x$, right?

No, $\lvert 0 \rvert = 0$, which is not positive and not negative.

> In which case, isn't $|z|$ always positive? Considering
>   $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, where $z=a+bi$.

No, if $r = 0$, thus $z=0$, then $\lVert z \rVert = 0$, which is not positive.

Now we are talking about the complex absolute value, which can be viewed as 2-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$: 
$$
\lVert z \rVert^2 = z \bar{z} = (\mbox{Re } z)^2+ (\mbox{Im } z)^2
$$ 
Among the properties it shares with the real version are:
$$
\lVert z \rVert \ge 0 \\
\lVert z \rVert = 0 \iff z = 0
$$